# how to split a string without delimiters?

Tags: javascript

I have string "513". I need array ["5", "1", "3"]. My [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/4ca06dyj/):

```
function nextBigger(num){
    let numStr = '' + num;
  let numArr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < numStr.length; ++i) {
    numArr.push(numStr[i]);
  }

  console.log(numArr);
}

nextBigger(513);
```

But this solution is large and redundant. I need shorter solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just `.split()` with an empty string as the delimiter. This will split the string at each character:

```js
function nextBigger(num){
  console.log(num.toString().split(""));
}

nextBigger(513);
```

Comment: "on an empty string" ?

Comment: @Adriani6 Yes, `""` is an empty string.

Comment: @Adriani6 are you asking what an empty string is?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ah right, of course. @Amy No, I just got confused, I was referring to `.toString()` to being an empty string. All sorted now, cheers :)

Comment: This works because [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):  "Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character."

Comment: No no, I know how it works thanks! :) I was just confused with the terminology used in this context, I got it all clear now :)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, that wasn't addressed to you.  I wanted to expand Scott's answer with some documentation.

Comment: @GolezTrol Scott didn't ask the question.  What are you talking about?

Comment: @GolezTrol i disagree with you wholeheartedly, this was a good answer.  If you think this question deserves a higher quality answer, why don't you write one?  Show us how it's done.

Comment: @Amy A better answer already exist (*note `.split('')` has issues that spread syntax solves*), it's in the linked duplicate. While this answer is fine, I see where *GolezTrol* is coming from. Generally there isn't a reason to answer a common question with a well known duplicate.

Comment: @GolezTrol This has nothing to do with the quality of the answer, which was your initial criticism.  The goal post has moved though, I see.

Comment: @Amy I thought that was implied when I wrote *"And that for a very simple question that must have been asked a dozen times at least."*, but apparently that was too vague. It certainly wasn't my intention to get in a fight like this or create this huge discussion. I pleaded for quick removal of a duplicate. If the response is to rather choose rep over quality, there is not much I can do, so I'll just remove my part of this useless discussion, and I hope you take care of yours. Business as usual. Don't know what I was thinking. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

With ES6, you could use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which takes an iterable and iterates the single items.

Or just take the power of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which does nearly the same (and much more).

```js
const getCharacters1 = string => [...string];
const getCharacters2 = string => Array.from(string);

console.log(getCharacters1('513'));
console.log(getCharacters2('513'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `numString.split('')`. (Two single quotes without space). That will return an array with all the characters.

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: Commented at the same moment. you did.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use .split() function.

```
"513".split("")
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Spread syntax** if you want something really short

`let a = [...'513']`